# GRC Shields Up test - are stealth ports good?

Tags: ports

I used Steve Gibson's ShieldsUp test at https://www.grc.com.

All Service Ports test says that everything is green (stealth) expect one blue (closed).
I tried several times and one time, it gave me 2 blue, rest green. Blue seems to change location/port.

```
GRC Port Authority Report created on UTC: 2017-01-09 at 12:30:20
Results from scan of ports: 0-1055

0 Ports Open

1 Ports Closed

1055 Ports Stealth

---------------------
1056 Ports Tested

NO PORTS were found to be OPEN.
The port found to be CLOSED was: 135
Other than what is listed above, all ports are STEALTH.
TruStealth: FAILED - NOT all tested ports were STEALTH,
- NO unsolicited packets were received,
- NO Ping reply (ICMP Echo) was received.

**Solicited TCP Packets: RECEIVED (FAILED) — As detailed in the port report below, one or more of your system's ports actively responded to our deliberate attempts to establish a connection. It is generally possible to increase your system's security by hiding it from the probes of potentially hostile hackers. Please see the details presented by the specific port links below, as well as the various resources on this site, and in our extremely helpful and active user community.**

Unsolicited Packets: PASSED — No Internet packets of any sort were received from your system as a side-effect of our attempts to elicit some response from any of the ports listed above. Some questionable personal security systems expose their users by attempting to "counter-probe the prober", thus revealing themselves. But your system remained wisely silent. (Except for the fact that not all of its ports are completely stealthed as shown below.)

Ping Echo: PASSED — Your system ignored and refused to reply to repeated Pings (ICMP Echo Requests) from our server.*
```

Is it good I got so many stealth?

But what about the TCP Packs failed?

Comment: A quick warning: The ShieldsUp scanner is known to give poor / bad results, and has (historically at least) used ridiculous marketing jargon to make it sound like it is more capable than it is. [Steve Gibson is generally considered to be a charlatan by the security industry](http://attrition.org/errata/charlatan/steve_gibson/). His actual security knowledge is flaky and outdated at best, but he is a charismatic salesman who gathers quite the following of lesser-experienced folks to his podcast and blog. Take anything he says or publishes with a very large pinch of salt.

Comment: @Polynomial Really? Thank you for telling me! I only found out about this test from one tech support forum... guess the guy in there did not know himself...

Answer (score 2):

That is explained on his [Internet Port Status Definitions](https://www.grc.com/su/portstatusinfo.htm) page:

> A "Stealth" port is one that completely ignores and simply "drops" any incoming packets without telling the sender whether the port is "Open" or "Closed" for business. When all of your system's ports are stealth (and assuming that your personal firewall security system doesn't make the mistake of "counter-probing" the prober), your system will be completely opaque and invisible to the random scans which continually sweep through the Internet.
>
> Even if this machine had previously been scanned and logged by a would-be intruder, a methodical return to this IP address will lead any attacker to believe that your machine is turned off, disconnected, or no longer exists. You couldn't ask for anything better. Your personal firewall or NAT router protected system is acting like a black hole for TCP/IP packets. That's very cool.

So yes, stealth is good. It's better then closed becaused closed ports tell an attacker *There's something here*. Especially with well-known ports they know what software is running behind those ports and could try attacking that (e.g. trying if [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) is supported).

Port 135 being closed is good; **all ports stealth** would be better (that 'says': *There's nothing here*).

As for the question about other ports not being stealth, we cannot say much more since you do not mention which ports they are, and what is keeping them open. That would be for you to investigate and is a different question.
There are plenty of [questions on this site about open ports](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+open+ports) (read those first)

Comment: Hello and thank you! Well, ALL of them are green, expect 135 that says it is closed. None are open (red). Guess that's good then.

Comment: OK, but you wrote *it gave me 2 blue, rest green. Blue seems to change location/port*. That is a contradiction with what you are saying now. Please update your question text if necessary.

Comment: I said that "everything is green (stealth) expect one blue (closed). I tried several times and one time, it gave me 2 blue, rest green. Blue seems to change location/port." Meaning I tried several times and almost always it gives me one blue, rest green, expect one time where I got 2 blue, rest green. And blue ports seem to change depending on test.