# Mixed results from different port scanners - stealth vs closed

Tags: ports, scan

I did some port scanning of the local network, as a bit of security due diligence, expecting the first 1000 to be stealthed. However, the results are mixed, when running the scan with different scanning tools.

### ShieldsUP!

https://www.grc.com
'All Service Ports' button

It consistently states that 1 - 1056 are all stealthed.

### Nmap

```
nmap -APn [ip address]
```

It states 'Host is up'. The results show only a handful as 'filtered' but the other 983 ports are summarized as `closed tcp ports (conn-refused)` - that certainly does not sound stealthed.

This was done from **outside** the local network. This means, from a linux box residing on a network at another physical location, without any VPN, thru the internet, to the public IP of the remote router to be scanned.

### Netcat

```
netcat -zn -vv -w 1 [ip address] 1-1000
```

The results nearly identical to nmap. It shows a handful as `timed out` - almost all the same ones that nmap shows as 'filtered' but the rest show as '(tcp) failed: Connection refused'

This was done from **outside** the local network, in same way as with tool 2

Already [searched](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=port%20scan%20stealth) many [other](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=is%3Aq%20closed%20stealth%20ports) threads...

[This thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147770/grc-shields-up-test-are-stealth-ports-good) mentions that grc.com is of poor credibility -

Within the router web config, no ports are set as open, and there does not seem to be any stealth related settings.

Is the discrepancy likely because grc.com is just wrong, nmap and netcat are right, and this old Dlink router is just junk and has no way to stealth its ports?

If not so, what can be done so that the network's public IP address and its ports do not appear to port scanners like nmap and netcat?

Upon rescanning without outgoing filters, it sure looks like said filters originally caused false results...

netcat with outgoing filters...
...port 1 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
...port 2 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
...port 3 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

netcat without outgoing filters...
...port 1 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
...port 2 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
...port 3 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress

nmap shows similar improvement when no outgoing filters:

```
All 1000 scanned ports on [ip address] are in ignored states.  
Not shown: 1000 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
```

...but one caveat - nmap recognizes the target IP address as a working, provisioned address, and sees its higher-level domain, i.e *.comcast.net, and in fact says "Host is up."

Can the target IP address be rendered fully invisible to port scanners, without much difficulty?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Please see edited post about local network. Also, there might be some outgoing filtering on the network from which the scans are run. Going to rerun the scans upon removing such filtering from the equation. Any additional suggestions for the next scans?

Comment: Excuse the nudge. As the edit shows, the redone scans were much better. Although, do the nmap results still say "Host is up." because it simply **assumes** so due to the `-Pn` option, but does not actually **know** whether the host is up or not?  

If it does not know whether the host is up, then how does it know *.comcast.net? Does it just get that from DNS servers, and thus knows it's a leased address, without knowing if the host is actually up?  

If so, then it seems you cannot make a public IP address actually invisible as that is perhaps an oxymoron?

Comment: nmap assumes that the host is up if the host seems to reply to data. It can not differ though if it is actually the target host or something in between which replies instead of the target host. The domain name reported is likely just from doing a reverse DNS lookup  on the IP address and has nothing to do with host being up or not.

Comment: Ok. This seems to settle the issue. If you'd like to enter your responses as an answer, would be glad to mark it as correct. Thank you for your help.